# Error on uploading image on aws s3 bucket

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3, swift2

I get this error on uploading image on aws s3 bucket:

> 2016-11-12 14:03:43.095 Let's Habit[5144:69128] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSConcreteData initWithBytes:length:copy:deallocator:]: absurd length: 18446744073709551615, maximum size: 9223372036854775808 bytes'

I am using following code for the request:

```
 let  fileURL :NSURL =  NSURL(string:"\(documentsUrl1)MyappDirectory")!
    let filePath = fileURL.path!
    let newimg :UIImage = (captureImage?.resizeWithPercentage(0.1))!
     let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newimg)
               print(imageData!.length)

    imageData!.writeToFile(filePath as String, atomically: true)

    let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
    uploadRequest.body = fileURL
    uploadRequest.key = fileName
    uploadRequest.bucket = S3BucketName

    self.upload(uploadRequest)


 func upload(uploadRequest: AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest) {
let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager()
    transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject! in
         print(task)
        if let error = task.error {
            if error.domain == AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain as String {
                if let errorCode = AWSS3TransferManagerErrorType(rawValue: error.code) {
                    switch (errorCode) {
                    case .Cancelled, .Paused:
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                        })
                        break;

                    default:
                        print("upload() failed: [\(error)]")
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    print("upload() failed: [\(error)]")
                }
            } else {
                print("upload() failed: [\(error)]")
            }
        }

        if let exception = task.exception {
            print("upload() failed: [\(exception)]")
        }

        if task.result != nil {
            print(task.result)

            let url = task.result
            print(url)


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in


      print("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/\(uploadRequest.bucket!)/\(uploadRequest.key!)")

            })
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Which line is causing the error? Is it `transferManager.upload()`?

Comment: in framework it will stop when i use breakpoints  on following code                                    NSInteger read = [self.stream read:chunkBuffer maxLength:defaultChunkSize];

    // mark end of stream if no data is read
    self.endOfStream = (read <= 0);

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:chunkBuffer length:read];

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The solution for me was to append the file name to the file URL which was pointing to a directory

```
uploadRequest.body = fileURL+fileName
```